# Implement the constant-Q transform in a custom audio encoder

Tags: sound, signal-processing, fourier-analysis

I'm working on a project in Wolfram Language where I need to implement the Constant Q Transform (CQT) in a custom audio encoder. The CQT is a time-frequency analysis method that is often used in music information retrieval (MIR) and audio signal processing, but it doesn't seem to be included in the built-in audio encoders in Wolfram.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-Q_transform

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'd typically give it a try yourself and then, if you get stuck, you can ask for help on a specific problem. Otherwise this may be too broad for a question.